# android sqlite match returns nothing

Tags: android, sqlite

this is my code to create an fts3 table

```
db.execSQL("CREATE VIRTUAL TABLE [videorecipes] USING FTS3 (" + "[recipeID] TEXT, " + "[recipeName] TEXT, " + "[video] TEXT, " + "[thumbs"] TEXT, " + "[ownerID"] TEXT, " + "[chefID"] TEXT, ");");
```

now if i queried it using something like this

```
Cursor c = sqlDatabase.rawQuery("select docid as _id, recipeID, recipeName, thumbs from videorecipes where ownerID = ? AND chefID = ?", new String[] { ownerID, chefID });
```

it works, i got the returned data, but when I tried to search using full text like this

```
Cursor c = sqlDatabase.rawQuery("select docid as _id, recipeID, recipeName, thumbs  from videorecipes  where recipeName MATCH ? AND ownerID = ? and chefID = ?, new String[] { searchRecipeName, ownerID, chefID  });
```

it returns nothing. i don't even know how to output any error from the sql error if there's any. by the way here's how I called the adapter

```
mCursor = dbAdapter.searchRecipe(searchString);

for(mCursor.moveToFirst(); mCursor.moveToNext(); mCursor.isAfterLast()) {
            alRecipeID.add(mCursor.getString(1));
}
```

did i do the full text search wrong?

note: the adapter above returns data if i didn't use the 'match' query to do full text search.

Comment: your for-loop is a tad bit broken, I guess you meant `for (mCursor.moveToFirst(); mCursor.isAfterLast(); mCursor.moveToNext())`. You can express that more succinctly as `while (mCursor.moveToNext())` btw.

Comment: @Android, uh.. [*no*, *no* times *ten*](http://www.sqlite.org/lang_createvtab.html).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

<del>For starters, this is nicer:</del>

```
for(mCursor.moveToNext()) {
   alRecipeID.add(mCursor.getString(1));
}
```

**Edit**:

```
while(mCursor.moveToNext()) {
   alRecipeID.add(mCursor.getString(1));
}
```

And your problem should be fixable if you just use the MATCH clause to filter your selection in full-text search, like this:

```
SELECT 
    docid as _id, 
    recipeID, 
    recipeName, 
    thumbs 
FROM 
    videorecipes 
WHERE 
    videorecipes 
MATCH 
    'recipeName:Yourtextgoeshere ownerID:1234 chefID:2345'
```

You'll have to manually format the MATCH-statement, since wildcards are going to work extraordinarily bad, something like this:

```
sqlDatabase.rawQuery("SELECT docid as _id, recipeID, recipeName, thumbs" +
    " FROM videorecipes WHERE videorecipes MATCH ?", 
    new String[]{"recipeName:Yourtextgoeshere ownerID:1234 chefID:2345"});
```

**Edit, now with example code**:
Tested on Android, and it sure seems to work just fine.

```
SQLiteOpenHelper helper = new SQLiteOpenHelper(this, "fts3.db", null, 1) {
    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {}
    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
        db.execSQL("CREATE VIRTUAL TABLE [videorecipes] USING FTS3 (" + "[recipeID] TEXT, "
                + "[recipeName] TEXT, " + "[video] TEXT, " + "[thumbs] TEXT, "
                + "[ownerID] TEXT, " + "[chefID] TEXT)");
    }
};

SQLiteDatabase db = helper.getWritableDatabase();
// Put something in the db
ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
for (int i = 0; i < 20; i++) {
    values.put("recipeID", i);
    values.put("recipeName", "Recipe #" + i);
    values.put("video", "Video" + i + ".avi");
    values.put("thumbs", "thumb" + i + ".jpg");
    // 10 for the ownerID 148 and 10 for the ownerID 1481
    values.put("ownerID", i < 10 ? "148" : "1481");
    values.put("chefID", i);
    db.insert("videorecipes", "chefID", values);
}

Cursor c = db.rawQuery("SELECT docid as _id, recipeID, recipeName, thumbs, ownerID " +
        "FROM videorecipes WHERE videorecipes MATCH ?" ,
        new String[]{"ownerID:1481 recipeName:Recipe"});

int count = c.getColumnCount();
while (c.moveToNext()) {
    for (int i = 0; i < count; i++) {
        System.out.println(c.getColumnName(i) + "=" + c.getString(i));
    }
    System.out.println("-----------------------------");
}
db.close();
```

Comment: and i tried doing this sqlDatabase.rawQuery("SELECT docid as _id, recipeID, recipeName, thumbs" +
    " FROM videorecipes WHERE videorecipes MATCH ?", 
    new String[]{"recipeName:Yourtextgoeshere"}); and the cursor returns nothing too.. by the way are you sure it's 'from videorecipes where videorecipes match?'.. and not something like 'from videorecipes where recipeName?'

Comment: i tried the sql query you gave above (or any query with match) in sqlite database browser (i pulled the db from my android emulator to my hard disk and open it using sqlite database browser) but it returns an error 'no such module: FTS3'

Comment: videorecipes is an fts3 document, so "from videorecipes WHERE videorecipes MATCH ?" should be the correct version. the SQLITE database browser you're using is probably compiled without FTS3 support - the code i supplied was just tested on android. Can you [recompile it](http://www.sqlite.org/fts3.html#section_2)?

Comment: the query still doesn't work for my android apps, but i tried this sqlDatabase.rawQuery("SELECT docid as _id, recipeID, recipeName, thumbs" +
    " FROM videorecipes WHERE recipeName MATCH ? '"+ searchRecipeName + "'", null});   ...any idea why this works?