# SQLiteDatabase Cursor empty only on Android 5.0+ devices

Tags: android, android-sqlite, android-cursor

The application has a `SearchView` which fetches suggestions from a specific database table. Everything worked without any errors until Android 5.0 appeared.

As of then, when the `SQLiteQueryBuilder` queries the database to fill the `Cursor` object, the return is empty cursor. Not `NULL`, but empty.

On other platforms, I can output the `Cursor`'s content via `DatabaseUtils.dumpCursorToString(cursorObject)`, but on Android 5.0+ the method reports output on null objects

> Dumping cursor null
>   <<<<<

Even more: when I extract database file from 5.0+ devices and run the local SQL query, I can fetch all data. So the database is valid indeed. And the query is the simplest one

```
SELECT rowid AS _id, suggest_text_1, suggest_text_2, rowid AS suggest_intent_data_id 
FROM fts 
WHERE (fts MATCH '*e*') //<-- I pressed "e" on the keyboard
```

The logic for selecting data from the database and filling the `Cursor` object is really simple

```
    SQLiteQueryBuilder builder = new SQLiteQueryBuilder();
    builder.setTables(FTS3_TABLE);
    builder.setProjectionMap(mColumnMap);

    Cursor cursor = builder.query(db,columns, selection, selectionArgs,
                                   null, null, null);
```

I tried looking for some deprecated methods, but was without any luck.

I have already spent 3 days debugging each step in the process and I am out of any ideas what could be causing such behaviour.

Anyone has any ideas?

EDIT

The output of the method `buildQuery()`

```
String query = builder.buildQuery(columns, selection, null, null, null, null);

RESULT:   
SELECT rowid AS _id, suggest_text_1, suggest_text_2, rowid AS suggest_intent_data_id  
FROM fts   
WHERE (fts MATCH ?)
```

`selection` and `selectionArgs` parameters are created like this

```
String selection = FTS3_TABLE + " MATCH ?";
String[] selectionArgs = new String[]{"*" + query + "*"};
```

The RAW query resulted the same thing as query via `builder.query()`

```
String query = builder.buildQuery(columns, selection, null, null, null, null);
Cursor temp = db.rawQuery(query, selectionArgs);
String output = DatabaseUtils.dumpCursorToString(temp);

Output: >>>>> Dumping cursor android.database.sqlite.SQLiteCursor@295023a7
        <<<<<
```

Comment: what does buildQuery() return?

Comment: i am referring to `String buildQuery()` method

Comment: what is your selection and selectionArgs ?

Comment: did you try to run that query using sqlite3 app on your device? or did you try to run SQLiteDatabase.rawQuery (String sql, String[] selectionArgs) ?

Comment: if db.rawQuery() produces an empty Cursor them you will know why SQLiteQueryBuilder produces an empty Cursor, see http://androidxref.com/5.1.0_r1/xref/frameworks/base/core/java/android/database/sqlite/SQLiteQueryBuilder.java#372

Comment: @pskink So even deeper debugging :(. Thanks for trying to help.

Comment: Conversation moved to http://stackoverflow.com/q/30709715/437039

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Answered https://stackoverflow.com/a/30710226/437039 by laalto

> `MATCH '*foo*'` queries never worked *correctly* in any version of sqlite. The fact that you got *some* results earlier was just a coincidence. Just the prefix form `MATCH 'foo*'` (and `MATCH 'foo'`) are [supported](http://www.sqlite.org/fts3.html#termprefix).
>
> [Lollipop ships with a newer version of sqlite](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2421189/version-of-sqlite-used-in-android). For detailed list of changes between sqlite versions, see the [changelog](http://www.sqlite.org/changes.html).

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to query using the SQLiteDatabase query method like the following?

```
String selection = "fts" + " =? AND " +

 String[] selectionArgs = new String [] {
                "*e*"
        };
 String[] projection = new String [] { "rowId", "suggested_text"};
 SQLiteDatabase db = mDbHelper.getReadableDatabase();
 Cursor cursor = db.query("tableName",
                projection,selection, selectionArgs, null, null, null);
```

Comment: I have to use `MATCH`. `=` will not work in this case

Comment: This may help resolve your issue : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16022427/android-sqlite-query-to-match-column-containing-text

Comment: This is also another link to someone with the same issue as you : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9428069/android-sqlite-match-returns-nothing