# MATCH with selectArgs looking like *queryTerm* stopped working on Android 5.0+

Tags: android, android-sqlite, android-5.0-lollipop

This is addendum to my question [SQLiteDatabase Cursor empty only on Android 5.0+ devices](https://stackoverflow.com/q/30668938/437039). That one will be closed as I was not sure what is causing the bug - thought it was a cursor note being properly filled.  Now I have discovered what is causing empty cursor.

Up to Android 5.0, search suggestions work by querying the database with the query:

```
SELECT rowid AS _id, suggest_text_1, suggest_text_2, rowid AS suggest_intent_data_id 
FROM fts 
WHERE (fts MATCH ?) //for example '*e*'
```

As of Android 5.0+, this does not work any more. I've done dozens of testings and the select query returns nothing to the `Cursor` object if I set `selectionArgs` to `"*" + query + "*"`

```
String selection = FTS3_TABLE + " MATCH ?";
String[] selectionArgs = new String[]{"*" + query + "*"};
```

On Android 5.0+ it will work ONLY if `selectionArgs` are either `query` or `query + "*"`. If I put asterisk before the `query`, it will stop working.

NOTE: I tested by querying a letter `e`, not a special character.

Database querying looks like this and it worked flawlessly up to Android 5.0:

```
String[] columns = new String[]{
                BaseColumns._ID,
                KEY_QUESTION,
                KEY_ANSWER,
                SearchManager.SUGGEST_COLUMN_INTENT_DATA_ID};
String selection = FTS3_TABLE + " MATCH ?";
String[] selectionArgs = new String[]{"*" + query + "*"};    

//mColumnMap
map.put(KEY_QUESTION, KEY_QUESTION);
map.put(KEY_ANSWER, KEY_ANSWER);
map.put(KEY_CARDID, KEY_CARDID);
map.put(KEY_CARDSET, KEY_CARDSET);
map.put(BaseColumns._ID, "rowid AS " +
         BaseColumns._ID);
map.put(SearchManager.SUGGEST_COLUMN_INTENT_DATA_ID, "rowid AS " +
                SearchManager.SUGGEST_COLUMN_INTENT_DATA_ID);
map.put(SearchManager.SUGGEST_COLUMN_SHORTCUT_ID, "rowid AS " +
                SearchManager.SUGGEST_COLUMN_SHORTCUT_ID);
//mColumnMap part ends

SQLiteQueryBuilder builder = new SQLiteQueryBuilder();
        builder.setTables(FTS3_TABLE);
        builder.setProjectionMap(mColumnMap);

Cursor cursor = builder.query(db,
                columns, selection, selectionArgs, null, null, null);

String temp = DatabaseUtils.dumpCursorToString(cursor); //empty string on Android 5.0+
```

As you can see, nothing complex or extraordinary.

Why I can no longer use query with asterisk on both sides of it?

What has changed as of Android 5.0 in this part?

Comment: Off the cuff, I would assume that SQLite changed the FTS query rules and [Android 5.0 is using a newer edition of SQLite](http://stackoverflow.com/a/4377116/115145). According to [the FTS documentation](http://www.sqlite.org/fts3.html), they support token and token-prefix queries, but I do not where they say that they support token-postfix or token-infix (which would be ones where the asterisk wildcard appears at the beginning).

Comment: From Android 5.0, you can search for the strings beginning with `*`. So it will not work. Wildcards can only be used as suffix as of now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`MATCH '*foo*'` queries never worked *correctly* in any version of sqlite. The fact that you got *some* results earlier was just a coincidence. Just the prefix form `MATCH 'foo*'` (and `MATCH 'foo'`) are [supported](http://www.sqlite.org/fts3.html#termprefix).

[Lollipop ships with a newer version of sqlite](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2421189/version-of-sqlite-used-in-android). For detailed list of changes between sqlite versions, see the [changelog](http://www.sqlite.org/changes.html).

Comment: Thanks. I personally never used it but found it in the code and got a bug when 5.0 appears.